# Where is the Hanuatu Island complex?

Tags: where-on-earth, islands, remote-locations

I came across this article:
http://worldnewsdailyreport.com/david-rockefellers-sixth-heart-transplant-successful-at-age-99/

[image]

Where a "Hanuatu Island complex" is mentioned and a photography of it attached. I was curious where exactly this island complex is located. Surprisingly enough I am unable to find anything but countless copies of this article and this photo.

Comment: World News Daily Report is a fake news site.  Most probably the whole story, including the existence of the island, is fictitious.

Comment: The photo is Neckar Island in British Virgin Islands owned by Richard Branson and available for private stays for a mere $78k per night.

Comment: @NateEldredge Apparently, this article has now been removed precisely for being fake.

Answer (score 9):

The island in the photo is actually [Necker Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necker_Island_(British_Virgin_Islands)) and is privately owned by Richard Branson, so it's most likely quite hard for the average traveller to visit.

[image]

World News Daily Report is actually a fake news website, as their [About](http://worldnewsdailyreport.com/about-us/) page states:

> World News Daily Report is an American Jewish Zionist newspaper based in Tel Aviv and dedicated on covering biblical archeology news and other mysteries around the Globe.

Comment: "so it's most likely quite hard for the average traveller to visit" - seeing as there is online booking, I'd disagree - http://www.virginlimitededition.com/en/necker-island/booking . Fairly pricey mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is a diocese (possibly an Island) in the Solomon Islands group called Hanuato, I don't know if this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score -3):

It's in Vanuatu, a South Pacific Ocean nation made up of roughly 80 islands that stretch 1,300 kilometers. The islands offer scuba diving at coral reefs, underwater caverns and shipwrecks.

Comment: While it's true that searching for "Hanuatu Island complex" will return hits for Vanuatu, I am not aware of any island in the chain with that name. The picture in the question has been identified as another island entirely - it appears the "Hanuatu Island complex" is fictional. If you are sure it's in Vanuatu, a scan of a map or link to a government web site including it would be helpful